# C# user controls

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

How to add controls in parent control
I am using C# windows application

I have a user control including group box and checkbox group box, controls gets enabled or  disabled on the basis of checked property of check box
now when using this control in other application 
how can i add controls in group box??
so that they can get enabled o disabled in my application

Comment: Could you post some samples of what you have so far?

Comment: ok
here is my code

in usercontrol i have a group box and a check box
and then i have written following code
foreach control ctrl in this.groupbox1.controls
{
if(ctrl!=this.checkbox1)
{
ctrl.enabled=this.checkbox1.checked;
}
}


this is my control now i want to use this control in other application
i want to know how i can add controls(panels,groupboxes) to this already made control

Comment: If you want to simply add additional controls to the user control itself, create a public method (similar to the one in the edited portion of my answer) that adds the controls to the user control (e.g.: `this.Controls.Add`) instead of to a container. Realize, however, that the added controls will be difficult to use without some sort of code that makes use of their properties, and in turn makes it available as properties or methods to the calling code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "bubble" a Controls features when place in a custom UserControl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785376/how-to-bubble-a-controls-features-when-place-in-a-custom-usercontrol)

Comment: That's an interesting feature of user controls and modifying the default designer behavior; I didn't know it could be done. Thanks Hans for the good information, as always. (Though I am still not sure if it applies to this question.)

Comment: well could u plz tell what is
 How to "bubble" a Controls features when place in a custom UserControl

and well my work is done!!!
thnks a lot.........

Comment: @MehaJain: The "How to bubble..." text in Hans' comment is a link, you can click on it for the further description.

Comment: thnks a lot
yaah my problem was a kind of how to bubble...
it was about dealing with parent control
however i was just trying to add my controls in the user control
you helped and i got it done
thnks a lot....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making an user control, in which I added a group box inside the check box.
So the group box is enabled and disable based on the check box.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to add controls via code (programatically) or using the designer?

If you want to add a control to a groupbox, panel, or other container, first you create the control:

```
Label myLabel = new Label();
myLabel.Name = "Name";
myLabel.Text = "Example";
myLabel.Location = new Point(10, 10);
```

Then, add it to the container using the container's Controls property, via the add method:

```
myGroupBox.Controls.Add(myLabel);
```

Finally, you can use the state of your checkbox to enable/disable the entire container (and all its child controls). You may want to use a boolean somewhere, but this is the basic idea:

In the CheckChanged event for your Checkbox, do this:

```
myGroupBox.Enabled = myCheckBox.Checked;
```

Or the inverse, depending on how you want the enabled state.

**EDIT:**

From your comment, it sounds like you want to add additional controls to an existing user control after design time. You would need to provide that functionality in a public method.

```
public void AddControl(Control controlToAdd)
{
    myGroupBox.Controls.Add(controlToAdd);
}
```

Basically exposing the user control container's `Controls.Add` to the code which interacts with your user control.

I hope this is helpful.

**EDIT 2:**

Here is the code you posted in a comment:

```
foreach(Control ctrl in this.groupbox1.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl != this.checkbox1)
    {
        ctrl.Enabled = this.checkbox1.Checked;
    }
}
```

This iterates through all the controls, and enables or disables all of them except checkbox1 based on checkbox1's checked state.

First, if checkbox1 is not a child control in groupbox1, there's no need for the if statement that ensures the current control *is not* checkbox1. It never will be, because the foreach is only iterating the child controls of groupbox1. As long as checkbox1 is outside of groupbox1, it is omitted from the iteration.

Second, it is much quicker and easier to maintain if you simply enable or disable the entire groupbox. All controls within it will inherit the enabled/disabled state. Using your control names the code would be:

```
groupbox1.Enabled = checkbox1.Checked;
```

I hope I am understanding your question correctly.

Comment: thanks for replying
well i know how to add controls
and i have actually made a usercontrol which is having a groupbox and a check box
now i want to use this usercontrol in my application
and there i want to add controls in my usercontrol 
is it really possible??

Comment: It sounds like you want to add controls to your user control after design time, i.e. programatically. You would need to provide a mechanism in your user control that allow you to add additional controls to it. I will edit my answer with an example.

Comment: yaah u got it right
bt can you plz tell how can i do this
i am a new programmer
what i should do??