# Using VS form designer to put controls in a container defined in a superclass?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, subclass, windows-forms-designer

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and I have a base class `Form`, and several other forms subclassing it.  I can create a container, such as a `Panel` in the parent form.  In the designers for the child forms though, I'm unable to create controls inside the container.  I tried setting the container to `protected`, but it doesn't appear to make any difference.

Is there any way I can create a container (I really want a `FlowLayoutPanel`) in the base class in a way that will allow me to interact with it in the designers for the subclasses?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "bubble" a Controls features when place in a custom UserControl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785376/how-to-bubble-a-controls-features-when-place-in-a-custom-usercontrol)

Comment: @Hans:  I don't believe it's a duplicate question.  That one deals with subclasses of controls.  I'm looking at subclasses of forms.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Modifiers flag of your panel to Protected.  Please also refer to the 
[Walkthrough: Demonstrating Visual Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z3efhd2.aspx) MSDN topic.

Comment: As my question states, I've already done that.  The caution note at the bottom of your link is helpful though.  It appears to suggest that what I want to do is impossible.