Custom ToolStrip removes PerfromLayout from Designer.cs file
Let's assume I've a Form and it contains a ToolStrip. In the Form1.Designer.cs file I can see the following to lines:
this.toolStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
this.toolStrip1.PerformLayout();

Let's assume I generate a custom ToolStrip using the following code:
[Designer(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner))]
public class MyToolStrip : ToolStrip
{
}

see WinForms ToolStrip not available in visual inheritence
If I use now MyToolStrip instead of ToolStrip in my Form then the this.toolStrip1.PerformLayout() line is removed from the designer file. Why? And how can I bring it back without editing every time the designer file which I shouldn't do?
If the line is missing the size of some controls is not right, e.g.: ToolStripComboBox
See as well C#: Does ResumeLayout(true) do the same as ResumeLayout(false) + PerformLayout()?

The ToolStrip's Designer overrides the SerializePerformLayout property, which is internal, so it always returns true, and it's mandatory for this Control, as you have noticed

@Jimi so I'm out of luck, because I can't override the SerializePerformLayout property because it's internal?

Or should I override the ResumeLayout(bool performLayout) method in MyToolStrip class so that it calls base.ResumeLayout(performLayout) and then PerformLayout()?

How do you override ResumeLayout()? Even if you could, that would be a run-time behavior, not design-time, if it's not called from the Designer itself. You're referring to designers and serialization, and your custom designer derives from ControlDesigner, which defaults to false when it comes to serialize PerformLayout(). Of course you cannot derive from ToolStripDesigner, since it's internal. You also need to be very careful with the SuspendLayout() / ResumeLayout() sequences, you may end up messing with the internal counter. The ToolStripDesigner is quite a complex class

You can modify the ActionList of the ToolStripDesigner this way instead of changing the type of the designer. See ToolStripDesigner.cs to understand why changing the designer here is not a good idea.

@dr.null If I remove the [Designer(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner))] and use the designerHost = Site.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost)) as IDesignerHost; approach then I'm not able to edit a ToolStrip in an inherited control.

Not sure if I understand your question. Do you mean the ToolStrip itself or as a child of a custom container (Form, UserControl, Panel...etc.)? Just in case, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8392672/14171304

As a child in a container, e.g.: Form. The ToolStrip is not private it's protected, but whitout [Designer(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner))] it s locked.

Preface:  This is based on my understanding that you want to use visual inheritance for the ToolStrip control, but allow inherited forms to modify the ToolStrip's 'Items` property that is normally not editable in the derived Form.
Warning:  This is a complete hack job and I have not evaluated the ramifications of implementing the tricks used to get the desired results.
----------
As was mentioned in the comments,the ControlDesigner class's property SerializePerformLayout returns "false" whereas the ToolStripDesigner class's property SerializePerformLayout returns "true".  This property is used in the ToolStripCodeDomSerializer class's Serialize method (actually this method is inherited from the ControlCodeDomSerializer class).  Specifically in this code fragment:
if (HasAutoSizedChildren(control) || (controlDesigner is not null && controlDesigner.SerializePerformLayout))
{
   SerializePerformLayout(manager, csCollection, value);
}

Since there is no way to override controlDesigner.SerializePerformLayout, this leaves us with finding a way to make HasAutoSizedChildren(control) evaluate to true.  A way to do so, is to add a hidden control to the ToolStrip's Controls collection.
public MyToolStrip() : base()
{
    Control c = new Control();
    c.Visible = false;
    c.MinimumSize = System.Drawing.Size.Empty;
    c.Size = System.Drawing.Size.Empty;
    c.AutoSize = true;
    Controls.Add(c);
}

Normally the ToolStrip does not parent controls but rather components deriving from the ToolStripItem class. In fact, its ControlCollection is readonly.  To solve this problem we need to override the CreateControlsInstance method.
protected override Control.ControlCollection CreateControlsInstance()
{
  return  new ControlCollection(this);
}

Wrapping this all up:
    [Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
    public class MyToolStrip : ToolStrip
    {
        public MyToolStrip() : base()
        {
            Control c = new Control();
            c.Visible = false;
            c.MinimumSize = System.Drawing.Size.Empty;
            c.Size = System.Drawing.Size.Empty;
            c.AutoSize = true;
            Controls.Add(c);
        }

        protected override Control.ControlCollection CreateControlsInstance()
        {
          return  new ControlCollection(this);
        }
    }

You still need to set the ToolStrip's Modifiers property to Protected in the base form's designer.
______________________________________________________________
Edit
To address the comment:

If I open now a form which contains this MyToolStrip I get the
following error: Unable to cast object of type ControlCollection to
type ReadOnlyControlCollection

I do not know what code is causing this exception, but it is possible to use Reflection to modify the ReadOnlyControlCollection to allow adding a control.  Also, to limit these hacks only to the design-time environment, the modifications are implemented only when the ToolStrip is sited to a designer.
[Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
public class MyToolStrip : ToolStrip
{
    public override ISite Site
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Site;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Site = value;
            if (value != null)
            {
                Control.ControlCollection cc = this.Controls; 
                Type t = cc.GetType(); // type System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsUtils+ReadOnlyControlCollection
                FieldInfo fiRO = t.GetField("_isReadOnly", (System.Reflection.BindingFlags)(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic));
                fiRO.SetValue(cc, false);
                Control c = new Control();
                c.Visible = false;
                c.AutoSize = true;
                cc.Add(c);
            }
        }
    }

}


If I open now a form which contains this MyToolStrip I get the following error: Unable to cast object of type ControlCollection to type ReadOnlyControlCollection.

@Wollmich, that error surprises me in that any code for the ToolStrip would make such an assignment.  Could you possibly post a stacktrace for the error?  In any case, I have posted an alternative that preserves the ReadOnlyControlCollection instance.
