# Create DesignMode for inner Panel With c# WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, controls

I have 2 panel in my Control.

panel 3 added to panel 1 for Title ,
panel 2 added to panel 1 For Content &
panel 1 is My Control

I do create this Control For my Project . 
this Control Code:

```
public class ControWithTitle : Panel // Panel 1
{
    public Panel Title = new Panel { Dock = DockStyle.Top, Height = 20, BackColor = Color.Black }; // Panel 2
    public Panel Content = new Panel { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, BackColor = Color.White }; // Panel 3
    public ControWithTitle ()
        : base()
    {

        this.Controls.Add(Title);
        this.Controls.Add(Content);
    }
}
```

I do When Add This control in Form > Create Design Mode For Content . not panel 1 Or Title Panel....

this Code not Work ... All Panel is Lock . after Build Project , every Changed was reset...

is work this true? How to create this?

```
 ╔═══════════╗ < Paenl 1
 ║╔═════════╗║
 ║║ Panel 2 ║║
 ║╚═════════╝║
 ║╔═════════╗║
 ║║         ║║
 ║║         ║║
 ║║         ║║
 ║║ Panel 3 ║║ < Design Mode For This Paenl
 ║║         ║║
 ║║         ║║
 ║║         ║║
 ║╚═════════╝║
 ╚═══════════╝
```

after pasted Dear @King's Code My Problem Not Solved... 
This Error has in my project:

[image]

this is my Code for a Other Sample After (@Hans Passant &  @King King) Answer:

```
    [Designer(typeof(CustomDesigner))]
public partial class ControlWithTitle : UserControl // Panel 1
{
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
    private ListView listView1 = new ListView();
    protected override void Dispose (bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null)) { components.Dispose(); }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    private void InitializeComponent ()
    {
        components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.Controls.Add(listView1);
    }
    public Panel Title = new Panel { };
    public Panel Content = new Panel { };

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public ListView Employees { get { return listView1; } }

    public ControlWithTitle ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
public class CustomDesigner : ParentControlDesigner
{
    public override void Initialize (IComponent component)
    {
        ControlWithTitle control = Control as ControlWithTitle;
        if (control != null)
        {
            EnableDesignMode(control.Employees, "Employees");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "bubble" a Controls features when place in a custom UserControl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785376/how-to-bubble-a-controls-features-when-place-in-a-custom-usercontrol)

Comment: hi Thanks . is Worked This Code For Panel Base Class ? or i do Create UserControl ?

Comment: It works fine for Panel as well, as King showed you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code, you have to add reference to the `System.Design.dll` and `using System.Windows.Forms.Design;`:

```
[Desiner(typeof(CustomDesigner))]
public class ControWithTitle : Panel // Panel 1
{
   //....
}
public class CustomDesigner : ParentControlDesigner {
   public override void Initialize(IComponent component){
      ControWithTitle control = Control as ControWithTitle;
      if(control != null){
        //Enable designmode for Panel3
        EnableDesignMode(control.Content, "Content");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: hi thanks . this Code Error > **Failure initializing the designer, it has no Component Member**

Comment: @M.Sabzaliyan wow, I tested it now, **It also works for Panel**, could you post the code you tried?

Comment: @M.Sabzaliyan is the error the same to what you commented before? Or there is not any error but simply it doesn't work?

Comment: is this .net Version ? my Framework is 4.0 / Visual Studio 2012... but is error(attash First Post)...