# How can I add controls to a tab control that is inside of a custom control, at design time?

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I have a custom control that is made up of two main controls, a `FlowLayoutPanel` on the left side, and a `TabControl` on the right side. The FLP is just used to store custom "buttons" that change the selected index of the tab control. I have it working at design time so that I can select the buttons and move through the pages.

I'm trying to make it so that I can drag controls to those pages, but the controls are just being added to the custom control.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this task?

Comment: Look [at this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785376/how-to-enable-design-support-in-a-custom-control) for an example that makes an embeddded ListView editable. It is more work than checking a property, though and extremly error-prone imo! Not really recommended..