# Add child to custom Control in Designer mode

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls

I have already seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2863807/939213)  for adding designer support to a custom Control. It works up to and including adding child Controls. Except that after closing the designer and opening it again - those children are gone.

Is there some way to get support for adding child Controls in the designer? Perhaps by some event that we can handle somehow "manually" (i.e. by my code)?

This is not a `UserControl`. It's a class inheriting from `Panel`.

Comment: Adding child controls in which designer? How? What exactly happens?

Comment: @SLaks You know the Winforms design mode, right? The one that gave Visual Studio its name. I want to drag a Control from the **Toolbox** and drop it on my `customControl1`'s (that is already on the `Form`) `panel1`, and have that new child Control added to `panel1`'s `Controls` property. The child is seen in the designer and in **Document outline**, but after I close the designer and reopen it - the child is gone.

Comment: You mean the form's designer, not the control's own designer.

Comment: @SLaks The Control does not have a designer. This is _not_ a user control. It's a custom control.

Answer (score 0):

You need to shadow or override the `Controls` property and apply `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]`.

This will tell the form's designer to save the contents of that property to its `.Designer.cs`.

Comment: Any idea how I would do that? It's a custom control - one that inherits from Panel. It's not a user control.

Answer (score 0):

For a class derived from `Panel`, the designer is enabled by default and you don't need to do anything, because the designer of panel is `PanelDesigner` which is derived from `ScrollableControlDeigner` which is derived from [`ParentControlDesigner`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.parentcontroldesigner(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7):

> `ParentControlDesigner` provides a base class for designers of
>   controls that can contain child controls. In addition to the methods
>   and functionality inherited from the `ControlDesigner` and
>   `ComponentDesigner` classes, `ParentControlDesigner` enables child
>   controls to be added to, removed from, selected within, and arranged
>   within the control whose behavior it extends at design time.

You can enable the designer by setting `ParentControldesigner` as designer of your control. For example:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
[Designer(typeof(ParentControlDesigner))]
public class MyControl : Control
{
}
```